# Using exported functions in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have 2 questions. How should i use exported functions and how can i use optional arguments?

I created a component just for functions and i want to call it by importing them to other components.

I'm exporting this function as:

```
    export const verifyOTP = (
      inputId: string,
      setIsVer: (state: boolean) => void | null,
      setProfile: () => void | null,
      setIsAuth: (state: boolean) => void
    ) => {
      let codeInput = document.getElementById(inputId) as HTMLInputElement;
      if (codeInput.value.length === 6) {
        let confirmationRes = window.confirmationRes;

    confirmationRes
      .confirm(codeInput.value)
      .then((res: any) => {
        setIsVer(true);
        setProfile();
        setIsAuth(true);
      })
      .catch((error: ErrorCallback) => console.log(error));
  }
};
```

And i'm calling it in an input as:

```
<input
              type="text"
              id="code"
              onChange={() => verifyOTP('code', null, null, setIsAuth)}
              placeholder="Código"
              disabled={disable}
            ></input>
```

In this component i just want it to trigger setIsAuth. But in another component i want to use all the 4 arguments.

It's throwing this error at the onChange:

```
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: boolean) => void | null'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about operator precedence:

`(state: boolean) => void | null` is actually a function that can either return `void` *or* `null`.

You want `((state: boolean) => void) | null` instead, which is a function that returns `void`, or just the value `null`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it says 'Cannot invoke object that's possibly null', so i tried `setIsVer && setIsVer(true);` and apparently it's working. Is there another better/smarter way to do it?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Yes, you can optionally call an expression if it is not null or undefined with `setIsVer?.(true)`. Looks wild, but it's to match optional chaining (`foo?.bar`).